# Check for a substring at the end of string

Tags: ruby, string, substring

Let's say I have two strings:

1. "This-Test has a "
2. "This has a-Test"

How do I match the "Test" at the end of string and only get the second as a result and not the first string. I am using `include?` but it will match all occurrences and not just the ones where the substring occurs at the end of string.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this very simply using `end_with?`, e.g.

```
"Test something Test".end_with? 'Test'
```

Or, you can use a regex that matches the end of the string:

```
/Test$/ === "Test something Test"
```

Answer (score 6):

```
"This-Test has a ".end_with?("Test") # => false
"This has a-Test".end_with?("Test") # => true
```

Answer (score 6):

Oh, the possibilities are many...

Let's say we have two strings, `a = "This-Test has a"` and `b = "This has a-Test`.

Because you want to match any string that ends exactly in `"Test"`, a good RegEx would be `/Test$/` which means "capital T, followed by `e`, then `s`, then `t`, then the end of the line (`$`)".

Ruby has the `=~` operator which performs a RegEx match against a string (or string-like object):

```
a =~ /Test$/ # => nil (because the string does not match)
b =~ /Test$/ # => 11 (as in one match, starting at character 11)
```

You could also use `String#match`:

```
a.match(/Test$/) # => nil (because the string does not match)
b.match(/Test$/) # => a MatchData object (indicating at least one hit)
```

Or you could use `String#scan`:

```
a.scan(/Test$/) # => [] (because there are no matches)
b.scan(/Test$/) # => ['Test'] (which is the matching part of the string)
```

Or you could just use `===`:

```
/Test$/ === a # => false (because there are no matches)
/Test$/ === b # => true (because there was a match)
```

Or you can use `String#end_with?`:

```
a.end_with?('Test') # => false
b.end_with?('Test') # => true
```

...or one of several other methods. Take your pick.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the regex `/Test$/` to test:

```
"This-Test has a " =~ /Test$/
#=> nil
"This has a-Test" =~ /Test$/
#=> 11
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a range:

```
"Your string"[-4..-1] == "Test"
```

You can use a regex:

```
"Your string " =~ /Test$/
```

Answer (score 3):

String's [`[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) makes it nice and easy and clean:

```
"This-Test has a "[/Test$/] # => nil
"This has a-Test"[/Test$/] # => "Test"
```

If you need case-insensitive:

```
"This-Test has a "[/test$/i] # => nil
"This has a-Test"[/test$/i] # => "Test"
```

If you want true/false:

```
str = "This-Test has a "
!!str[/Test$/] # => false

str = "This has a-Test"
!!str[/Test$/] # => true
```